# how to communicate telegram bot with google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

i have problem for communication with telegram bot and google Spreadsheet , yesterday i work with that , and work very good, but today it can't work.
i create another google account and and another Bot, but not work.
this is my google script :

```
var token="123197063:AAH04kulz7tRqPz3vbDcgYdVje18WH2Pv-4";
var telegramUrl= "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwqvJWsWcm_5_Y1vhYEkSN2G9dxiDBzQIvYvbte-3_HfGcGFN3a/exec";

function getMe(){
  var url = telegramUrl+"/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl+"/setWebhook?url="+webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}

function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("hi this is my first project");

}

function dePost(e){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "message from bot", JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));

}
```

in this code when i write anything in telegram bot , google sheet must send an email to me, but it can't work today.
and this is my Bot address: @irmec_bot

do you have idea that it not work?
please help to me
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may follow the instructions in this video tutorial: [How to connect your Telegram Bot to a Google Spreadsheet (Apps Script) Script in Description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSXd_od4Lg).

```
// 
// FILL IN THE GLOBAL VARIABLES token, webAppUrl and ssId
//

var token = ""; // FILL IN YOUR OWN TOKEN
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = ""; // FILL IN YOUR GOOGLE WEB APP ADDRESS
var ssId = ""; // FILL IN THE ID OF YOUR SPREADSHEET

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(id,text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");
}

function doPost(e) {
  // this is where telegram works
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment " + text;
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);

  if(/^@/.test(text)) {
    var sheetName = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
    var comment = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name,comment,answer]);
  }
}
```

Here's an additional reference which might also help: [Telegram Bot with Apps Script](http://ocordova.me/blog/telegram-bot-with-apps-script)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a new script for the same bot, you should set the web hook to the new link.

1) After you publish as app, copy the given a url (some thing like > `https://script.google.com/macros/s/...` )

2) Replace the url on line 3 `var webAppUrl = INSERT_URL_HERE`

3) Save the script

4) Run the `setWebhook()` function by clicking Run > Run Function > setWebhook()

Hope this helps!